# ruby how to read hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, loops

Controller code:

```
def index
  @folders = Folder.where(parent_id: 0, user_id: current_user)
  @subfolders = Hash.new()
  @folders.each_with_index do |folder, index|
    @subfolders[folder.id] = { folder.id => Folder.where(parent_id: folder.id) }
  end
end
```

View:

```
<% @folders.each_with_index do |folder, index| %>
  <td><%= folder.name %></td><br />
  @subfolders[index].name
<% end %>
```

the @subfolders[1].to_s object itself returns this result:

```
{1=>#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Folder id: 2, name: "tt", user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-06-21 19:29:32", updated_at: "2014-06-21 19:29:32", parent_id: 1>]>}
```

My question is , how to read this @subfolders Hash in view ? I want to display subfolder after parent is displayed... Please help

Comment: I think `@subfolders[folder.id]` will be `@subfolders[index]` Right ?

Comment: `@subfolders[folder.id][folder.id]` will do. but why you need such strange chaining.

Comment: Yes, thats working, but you right actually. The thing is, once i read all the parent folders, i need collection to store its subfolders, thats why i decided to use hases. If you have any suggestions please let me know? Is it possible to rewrite using arrays ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is seems to be a more efficient solution to your problem as it runs 2 queries while yours generates an [`n + 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue)

```
ids = Folder.where(parent_id: 0, user_id: current_user).pluck(:id)
@subfolders = Folder.where(parent_id: ids).group_by(:parent_id)
```